# Overriding the default WP Multisite notification e-mail

Tags: multisite, email, notifications

Is it possible to hook in and override the default notification message for WP MS? I know the message being sent out is in /wp-admin/user-new.php

```
if ( is_multisite() ) {
    function admin_created_user_email( $text ) {
        /* translators: 1: Site name, 2: site URL, 3: role */
        return sprintf( __( 'Hi,
You\'ve been invited to join \'%1$s\' at
%2$s as a %3$s.
If you do not want to join this site please ignore
this email. This invitation will expire in a few days.

Please click the following link to activate your user account:
%%s' ), get_bloginfo('name'), site_url(), esc_html( $_REQUEST[ 'role' ] ) );
    }
    add_filter( 'wpmu_signup_user_notification_email', 'admin_created_user_email' );

    function admin_created_user_subject( $text ) {
        return "[" . get_bloginfo('name') . "] Your site invite";
    }
}
```

I believe I can do it if I can find the right hook in so that I can remove_filter() and then add my own in. I had been toying with the following (admin_created_user_email2 is my new function):

```
function reset_admin_email(){
    remove_filter( 'wpmu_signup_user_notification_email', 'admin_created_user_email' );
    add_filter( 'wpmu_signup_user_notification_email', 'admin_created_user_email2', 1 );
}
```

I was reading this page that [lists the actions/hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_an_Admin_Page_Request) I can tie into, but I can't figure out which one to use (if any of them will even work)

Does anyone have experience with this to point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Levi

Comment: Thanks for sharing code guys, but none of these worked, I tried all of them on multisite. Has anyone gotten any of these to work?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to override the multi-site notification email by adding these:

```
remove_filter('wpmu_signup_user_notification_email','admin_created_user_email');
add_filter('wpmu_signup_user_notification_email',<function_name_here>);
add_filter('wpmu_signup_user_notification',<function_name_here>);
add_filter('wpmu_signup_user_notification_subject',<function_name_here>);
```

Adding the three filters at bottom i.e. email,notification and subject allows you to override the content and the subject of the email.

Answer (score 2):

@user2647 seems to be on the right path, but I think that this is more correct:

```
remove_action( 'wpmu_new_user', 'newuser_notify_siteadmin' );
add_action( 'wpmu_new_user', 'my_notification' );

function my_notification ($user_id) {
  // Make your custom notification here.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`remove_filter` has no effect because /wp-admin/user-new.php runs

`add_filter('wpmu_signup_user_notification_email', admin_created_user_email);`

every time it loads, after plugins_loaded.

I got this to work by adding a new filter with a *lower* priority (higher number), so it runs after `admin_created_user_email`, which has the default priority (10):

```
function reset_admin_email(){
    add_filter( 'wpmu_signup_user_notification_email', 'admin_created_user_email2', 11 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this kind of thing work?

```
if ( !function_exists('wp_new_user_notification') ) {
function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $plaintext_pass = '' ) {
    $user = new WP_User($user_id);

    $user_login = stripslashes($user->user_login);
    $user_email = stripslashes($user->user_email);
            $message = $user_login . " " . $user_email;

    wp_mail($user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your username and password'), get_option('blogname')), $message);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Dylan](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/29376/dylan-barlett) has the correct answer but to elaborate.

Add a filter that fires after the default one using a higher priority then 10:

```
add_filter( 'wpmu_signup_user_notification_email', 'wp_new_user_notification', 11 );
```

The function for the content:

```
function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $plaintext_pass = '' ) {

            $user = new WP_User( $user_id );

            $user_login = stripslashes( $user->user_login );
            $user_email = stripslashes( $user->user_email );

            $message  = sprintf( __('New user registration on %s:'), get_option('blogname') ) . "\r\n\r\n";
            $message .= sprintf( __('Username: %s'), $user_login ) . "\r\n\r\n";
            $message .= sprintf( __('E-mail: %s'), $user_email ) . "\r\n";

            @wp_mail(
                get_option('admin_email'),
                sprintf(__('[%s] New User Registration'), get_option('blogname') ),
                $message
            );

            if ( empty( $plaintext_pass ) )
                return;

            $message  = __('Hi there,') . "\r\n\r\n";
            $message .= sprintf( __("Welcomeeee to %s! Here's how to log in:"), get_option('blogname')) . "\r\n\r\n";
            $message .= wp_login_url() . "\r\n";
            $message .= sprintf( __('Username: %s'), $user_login ) . "\r\n";
            $message .= sprintf( __('Password: %s'), $plaintext_pass ) . "\r\n\r\n";
            $message .= sprintf( __('If you have any problems, please contact me at %s.'), get_option('admin_email') ) . "\r\n\r\n";
            $message .= __('Adios!');

            wp_mail(
                $user_email,
                sprintf( __('[%s] Yourrrrrrr username and password'), get_option('blogname') ),
                $message
            );
        }
```

- This code is a copy paste from [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_new_user_notification) example.
- Referenced directly in [core here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/ms-functions.php#L875).

Finally drop it into the [mu-plugins folder](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) `wp-content/mu-plugins`

Answer (score 0):

Most of the text in those emails is translatable, which means we can tap into WP's [gettext](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext) filter. I found the following method of implementing translations online but can't find the original source.

First define your filter hook:

`add_filter('gettext', [new AddAction(), 'gqa_text_strings'], 20, 3);`

Then your translation function:

```
 /**
 * Change a few text strings related to the login/registration process
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext
 *
 * @param $translated_text
 * @param $text
 * @param $domain
 *
 * @return string
 */
function gqa_text_strings($translated_text, $text, $domain)
{
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'Get your own %s account in seconds' :
            $translated_text = __('Request access to %s', 'gqa');
            break;
        case 'We send your registration email to this address. (Double-check your email address before continuing.)' :
            $translated_text = __('', 'gqa');
            break;
        case 'But, before you can start using your new username, <strong>you must activate it</strong>.' :
            $translated_text = __('An email with login instructions has been sent to the address you provided.', 'gqa');
            break;
        case "Check your inbox at %s and click the link given." :
            $translated_text = __('Check your inbox at %s.', 'gqa');
            break;
        case 'If you do not activate your username within two days, you will have to sign up again.' :
            $translated_text = __('', 'gqa');
            break;
        // Subject line for new user registration email
        case 'New %1$s User: %2$s' :
            $translated_text = __('Your account information');
            break;
        // Error message when registering a new account with an already used username.
        case 'That username is currently reserved but may be available in a couple of days.' :
            $translated_text = __('A user with that username already exists. Do you already have an account? Please contact site administrators or try again.');
            break;
        // Error message when registering a new account with an already used email address.
        case 'That email address has already been used. Please check your inbox for an activation email. It will become available in a couple of days if you do nothing.' :
            $translated_text = __('That email address has already been assigned to an account. Do you already have an account? Please contact site administrators or try again');
            break;
    }

    return $translated_text;
}
```

You know a string is translatable if it's enclosed in the [__() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/). So in your case you would add the following:

```
case 'Hi, You\'ve been invited to join \'%1$s\' at
%2$s as a %3$s. If you do not want to join this site please ignore
this email. This invitation will expire in a few days. Please click the following link to activate your user account: %%s' :
    $translated_text = __('Whatever you want the email to say', 'gqa');
    break;
```