# Activation Account Email

Tags: multisite, email, activation

I use a betnami hosted wordpress multisite, when a user sign up in the site he should receive an email with activation link, but it does not work! so how to make it work? and if it work how to customize the email that the user receive.

Best Regards

Comment: Thanks for the help, i will solve the problem using your answers and get back to you as soon as possible.
Thanks again
best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if PHP mail is working in your server or debug WP's mail, there are several ways to do this, I would first test if a basic PHP mail function works.

The is as simple as running this from a PHP file or the command line:

```
 mail ('your@email.com', "Test", "Test mail from wordpress");
```

Find out what mail service is on your sever and debug it (sendmail, exim, etc, ?).

There are also some plugins that can help you debug email by sending test emails with custom headers on wordpress.org, as well as switching from PHP mail to SMTP (local or 3rd party).

To customize the activation email for multisite use the `wpmu_signup_user_notification_email` filter, for example:

```
  function wp176598_new_user_notification( $user_id, $plaintext_pass = '' ) {

     $message = "your custom message";

     wp_mail(
                $user_email,
                sprintf( __('Your login info for'), get_option('blogname') ),
                $message,
                $headers
            );
}
add_filter( 'wpmu_signup_user_notification_email', 'wp176598_new_user_notification',11 );
```

Additionally there is : `wpmu_signup_user_notification_subject` for the subject line

More info:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail
- [Overriding the default WP Multisite notification e-mail](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23867/overriding-the-default-wp-multisite-notification-e-mail)
- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/ms-functions.php#L883

Answer (score 0):

If that is a share hosting account then you are most likely facing a wait time on PHP's mail() functionality. Have you access to an SMTP service? If so, have you hooked wordpress up to an SMTP server and tried to pass through emails this way?

After you acquire SMTP access, you can use this plugin @ wordpress.org

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Wishing you all the luck. It is very hard to help your problem with so little details about the server, hosting, and domain.

Thanks,
Andrew